Cyberpunk esque movie. A woman is created artificially from a multicolored skeleton and then escapes
I watched it when I was really young. There's this orange/multicolored skeleton in a pod and these scientists bring it to life as a woman, who then somehow escapes into a flying taxi (the movie, if I recall, was futuristic/cyberpunk themed.) They are pursued by someone, I can't exactly recall who.
The lady, at first, has poor intelligence, and cannot even read, but throughout the film gets smarter.
I think at the end of the movie she falls in love with the taxi driver.

This is The Fifth Element (1997)
Leeloo is reborn from a skeleton



She conveniently falls into the taxi of the only man on Earth who can help her.




Could be... I recall a scene where she tried to read a road sign and I feel like the skeleton was multicolored. However in the scene the part where they start to revive her maybe that part where she's scanned is what I'm thinking of? I'll have to watch the movie

This does seem to be the movie I'm thinking of though. Thank you!

done. Thanks again.

@Joey - You're very welcome indeed.
